# Is it an antipattern to await multiple promises in this way?

Tags: javascript

The following emits an `unhandledrejection` event, but otherwise seems to "work".

`for...await` seems to respond to the rejected promise by emitting an exception (albeit after the first promise has resolved).

I can avoid the `unhandledrejection` event using `Promise.all` and `Promise.allSettled`. Is the following code an antipattern?

```js
async function asyncFunction() {
    try {
        const happy = new Promise((resolve)=>setTimeout(()=>resolve('success'), 1000))
        const sad = new Promise((_,reject)=>setTimeout(()=>reject('failure')))
        const promises = [happy, sad]
        for await(const item of promises) {
            console.log(item)
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`an error occurred:`, err)
    }
}

asyncFunction()
```

Comment: Using a built-in statement is never an anti-pattern. It totally depends on how you use it and for what purpose. And at least the purpose of your script is not clear at all.

Comment: All anti-patterns use "built-in statements", otherwise they wouldn't be valid code.

Comment: Don't stop reading my comment after the first sentence ;) _**It totally depends on how you use it and for what purpose**. And at least the purpose of your script is not clear at all._

Comment: Something can not "never" be the case, and also at the same time "depend on how you use it". Your comment is logically inconsistent, but whatever. Meh.

Comment: No reason for getting rude here... What would you call the [explicit construction (deferred) anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)? Using `new Promise()` is good/bad/an anti-pattern? No. But using a new Promise that acts on another (implicit) Promise is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Agree. But neither my question, nor my comments, asserted otherwise. The crux of my question is: "is this formulation of valid code, an anti-pattern, given that an uncaught error event can be emitted?" Seems a fair question. Even with six upvotes, you brigaded it to closed, meaning the people who want to know the answer are left hanging.

Comment: I re-asked the question and got an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60706179/using-for-await-of-with-synchronous-iterables#60707105. In short: yes it's an antipattern as-of ES2020.